# AWS Transcribe S3 .wav file to text

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

I am trying to use aws Transcribe to convert a wav file to text.  I have uploaded a wav file to S3, which is located here and it has public read/write permissions: https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/csld8xmsdksdf8s9sk3mmdjsdifkjksdijsldk/Transcribe2.wav.  The wav file is valid.  I can download it in my browser and replay it (and it sounds like the origin recording), so I think we can rule out an invalid input file, file permissions, etc.

I am using java version: 1.8.0_275 for mac.

I expect my program to give me back the transcribed text: "Hello amazon Subscribe, what is this?"

Here is the actual program output, including exception:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=60898:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/cdornin/work/transcribe/target/classes:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.0.0/apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.4.0/junit-platform-commons-1.4.0.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/transcribe/2.15.65/transcribe-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/protocol-core/2.15.65/protocol-core-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/aws-json-protocol/2.15.65/aws-json-protocol-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/sdk-core/2.15.65/sdk-core-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/profiles/2.15.65/profiles-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.2/reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/2.15.65/auth-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/eventstream/eventstream/1.0.1/eventstream-1.0.1.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/http-client-spi/2.15.65/http-client-spi-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/regions/2.15.65/regions-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/annotations/2.15.65/annotations-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/utils/2.15.65/utils-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/aws-core/2.15.65/aws-core-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/metrics-spi/2.15.65/metrics-spi-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/apache-client/2.15.65/apache-client-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.11/httpcore-4.4.11.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/netty-nio-client/2.15.65/netty-nio-client-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.53.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http2/4.1.53.Final/netty-codec-http2-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.53.Final/netty-codec-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.53.Final/netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.53.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.53.Final/netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.53.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.53.Final/netty-handler-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.53.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.53.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.53.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/netty/netty-reactive-streams-http/2.0.4/netty-reactive-streams-http-2.0.4.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/netty/netty-reactive-streams/2.0.4/netty-reactive-streams-2.0.4.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/awssdk/transcribestreaming/2.15.65/transcribestreaming-2.15.65.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.11.939/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.939.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/1.11.939/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.939.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.939/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.939.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/software/amazon/ion/ion-java/1.0.2/ion-java-1.0.2.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor/2.6.7/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.8.1/joda-time-2.8.1.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/jmespath-java/1.11.939/jmespath-java-1.11.939.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-transcribe/1.11.939/aws-java-sdk-transcribe-1.11.939.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/io/minio/minio/8.0.3/minio-8.0.3.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/carrotsearch/thirdparty/simple-xml-safe/2.7.1/simple-xml-safe-2.7.1.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/2.11.1/checker-qual-2.11.1.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.4/error_prone_annotations-2.3.4.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/4.8.1/okhttp-4.8.1.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okio/okio/2.7.0/okio-2.7.0.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.70/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.70.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.2/jackson-annotations-2.11.2.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.2/jackson-core-2.11.2.jar:/Users/cdornin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.2/jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar com.amazonaws.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeServiceImpl
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 30
log4j:WARN Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 30
log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.
log4j:ERROR DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.model.AmazonTranscribeException: null (Service: AmazonTranscribe; Status Code: 400; Error Code: null; Request ID: 6BBE51FDC2CA981B; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.doInvoke(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:1995)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.invoke(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:1962)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.invoke(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:1951)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.executeStartTranscriptionJob(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:1712)
    at com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClient.startTranscriptionJob(AmazonTranscribeClient.java:1681)
    at com.amazonaws.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeServiceImpl.callTranscribeService(AmazonTranscribeServiceImpl.java:34)
    at com.amazonaws.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeServiceImpl.main(AmazonTranscribeServiceImpl.java:20)
```

Here is my java code (add your aws key and secret)

```
package com.amazonaws.transcribe;

import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribe;
import com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.AmazonTranscribeClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.model.Media;
import com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.model.StartTranscriptionJobRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.transcribe.model.StartTranscriptionJobResult;

/**
 * @author ravindu.s
 */
public class AmazonTranscribeServiceImpl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", "myKey");
        System.setProperty("aws.secretAccessKey", "mySecret");
        callTranscribeService("https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/csld8xmsdksdf8s9sk3mmdjsdifkjksdijsldk/Transcribe2.wav");
    }


    public static void callTranscribeService(String mediaFile) {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfig.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
        clientConfig.setMaxConnections(100);
        clientConfig.setSocketTimeout(60000);

        AmazonTranscribe transcribeClient = AmazonTranscribeClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(
                DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()).withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(mediaFile, "us-east-1")).withClientConfiguration(clientConfig).build();
        StartTranscriptionJobRequest request = buildRequest(mediaFile);
        StartTranscriptionJobResult response = transcribeClient.startTranscriptionJob(request);
        System.out.println(response.getTranscriptionJob().getTranscriptionJobStatus());
    }

    private static StartTranscriptionJobRequest buildRequest(String mediaFile) {
        StartTranscriptionJobRequest request = new StartTranscriptionJobRequest();
        request.setMediaSampleRateHertz(16000);
        request.setMediaFormat("wav");
        request.setLanguageCode("en-US");
        request.setTranscriptionJobName("JOB-001");
        Media media = new Media();
        media.setMediaFileUri(mediaFile);
        request.setMedia(media);

        return request;
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>play</groupId>
    <artifactId>transcribeTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>transcribe</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.65</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/transcribestreaming -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>transcribestreaming</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.65</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.939</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-transcribe -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-transcribe</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.939</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.minio</groupId>
            <artifactId>minio</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.3</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a small mistake in my code.  This line wasn't necessary and when I removed, it worked:

```
withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(mediaFile, "us-east-1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java Code Example that transcribes an audio file located in C:. This is V2.

```
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.transcribestreaming.TranscribeStreamingAsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.transcribestreaming.model.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;


public class TranscribeStreamingDemoFile {
    private static final Region REGION = Region.US_EAST_1;
    private static TranscribeStreamingAsyncClient client;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, LineUnavailableException {

        client = TranscribeStreamingAsyncClient.builder()
                .region(REGION)
                .build();

        CompletableFuture<Void> result = client.startStreamTranscription(getRequest(16000),
                new AudioStreamPublisher(getStreamFromFile()),
                getResponseHandler());

        result.get();
        client.close();
    }

    private static InputStream getStreamFromFile() {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("C:\\test.wav");
            InputStream audioStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            return audioStream;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

  private static StartStreamTranscriptionRequest getRequest(Integer mediaSampleRateHertz) {
        return StartStreamTranscriptionRequest.builder()
                .languageCode(LanguageCode.EN_US)
                .mediaEncoding(MediaEncoding.PCM)
                .mediaSampleRateHertz(mediaSampleRateHertz)
                .build();
    }

    private static StartStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler getResponseHandler() {
        return StartStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler.builder()
                .onResponse(r -> {
                    System.out.println("Received Initial response");
                })
                .onError(e -> {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + sw.toString());
                })
                .onComplete(() -> {
                    System.out.println("=== All records stream successfully ===");
                })
                .subscriber(event -> {
                    List<Result> results = ((TranscriptEvent) event).transcript().results();
                    if (results.size() > 0) {
                        if (!results.get(0).alternatives().get(0).transcript().isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println(results.get(0).alternatives().get(0).transcript());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    private static class AudioStreamPublisher implements Publisher<AudioStream> {
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private static Subscription currentSubscription;


        private AudioStreamPublisher(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super AudioStream> s) {

            if (this.currentSubscription == null) {
                this.currentSubscription = new SubscriptionImpl(s, inputStream);
            } else {
                this.currentSubscription.cancel();
                this.currentSubscription = new SubscriptionImpl(s, inputStream);
            }
            s.onSubscribe(currentSubscription);
        }
    }

    public static class SubscriptionImpl implements Subscription {
        private static final int CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 1024 * 1;
        private final Subscriber<? super AudioStream> subscriber;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        private AtomicLong demand = new AtomicLong(0);

        SubscriptionImpl(Subscriber<? super AudioStream> s, InputStream inputStream) {
            this.subscriber = s;
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public void request(long n) {
            if (n <= 0) {
                subscriber.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("Demand must be positive"));
            }

            demand.getAndAdd(n);

            executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    do {
                        ByteBuffer audioBuffer = getNextEvent();
                        if (audioBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
                            AudioEvent audioEvent = audioEventFromBuffer(audioBuffer);
                            subscriber.onNext(audioEvent);
                        } else {
                            subscriber.onComplete();
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (demand.decrementAndGet() > 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            executor.shutdown();
        }

        private ByteBuffer getNextEvent() {
            ByteBuffer audioBuffer = null;
            byte[] audioBytes = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES];

            int len = 0;
            try {
                len = inputStream.read(audioBytes);

                if (len <= 0) {
                    audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(0);
                } else {
                    audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(audioBytes, 0, len);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }

            return audioBuffer;
        }

        private AudioEvent audioEventFromBuffer(ByteBuffer bb) {
            return AudioEvent.builder()
                    .audioChunk(SdkBytes.fromByteBuffer(bb))
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that example.  Uploading and transcribing a local file is a different use case which I also want to do.  While your submission is helpful, it doesn't answer the question I asked which was how to transcribe an S3 media file.

Comment: I tried your solution with a couple of different .wav files which I successfully transcribed using aws-cli (so the files are fine).  I get back empty results without any transcription data.  Any idea why?

Comment: Did you get back any results - or did it simply not write out any data.

Comment: My comment was incorrect, I see on closer inspection.  I am getting incorrect results (here's 3 of them): Okay?Yeah.Yeah.  The majority of the content isn't transcribed.

Comment: We are investigating that - the code is correct as we are passing an input stream based on the WAV file.

Comment: See this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836411/problem-aws-transcript-wav-file-to-text